# Rebinning histogram for goodness-of-fit test: p-hacking?

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, goodness-of-fit, histogram

I need to fit a 7-parameter function (actually 6 since one of them is fixed) on a histogram using ROOT. The function is basically an asymetric gaussian curve. The algorithm I'm using actually makes between 20 and 1000 fits and keeps the parameters that produces the highest p-value.

After each try, the code makes a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test to check whether or not the p-value is at least 0.05; and it stops trying when enough fits have produced a p-value over this limit. My problem is that the p-values I get are all *way* smaller than 0.05 (sometimes as low as 10$^{-200}$), even though the resulting curve fits correctly to my data. Here is an example :

[image: Example of fit that looks OK, but gives a p-value of 10$^{-7}$.]

As you can see, the fit seems to be OK, but the p-value for this particular set was around 5$\times$10$^{-7}$ (ROOT indicates that $\chi^2$ = 168.8 and that there are 88 degrees of freedom, since only about 90% of the histogram was used for the fit). With such p-values, the algorithm always tries to make 1000 fits even though the results do not get better, and I have over 60,000 datasets to fit, so the computation time is needlessly horribly long.

I thought maybe there are too many degrees of freedom, or maybe my histogram is too "noisy" for the goodness-of-fit test to be relevant. I thought I could rebin my histogram, maybe regroup bins in pairs as to lower the importance of random fluctuations. However, I wonder if this method is legitimate? Isn't it some form of p-hacking, ie presenting the data in a way that will make my fit more valid than in reality? Of course, I will remake the fit on the rebinned histogram (and not keep the initial parameters on the new histogram), but I expect the parameters to be only slightly modified (except for the amplitude, which is not important for my study). The point is that it should lower the chi-squared (faster than the number of degrees of freedom I hope) and increase the p-value, thus making the fit "more valid". Hopefully this way the algorithm won't have to make 1000 unnecessary tries to fit the data.

Is rebinning the best solution here? How much would be enough; and more importantly, how much is too much? Of course, I could present my data in a 3-bin histogram and the chi-squared would be pretty low, but this seems like cheating (and I really want to get the best parameters for my data, not just "a good fit"). Should I limit my test to a smaller interval of the histogram? Or should I try another goodness-of-fit test?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks a lot.

---

I'm editing to bump the question, as many details have been added in the comments below, and to include more people in the discussion. As noted by @Kodiologist, there might be a better method to fit the distribution than to put it in a histogram, I would like to get opinions on the matter. I thought I could fit the CDF instead of the PDF, but since the function I'm fitting is only a *surrogate* function (read: approximate), I'm not sure the CDF would give better results. Also, the exact form of the CDF has not been described anywhere. It could be derived, but perhaps it is not easy to do.

Comment: "I need to fit a 7-parameter function (actually 6 since one of them is fixed) on a histogram" — Why? Provide [context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl).

Comment: There are objective criteria for determining bin width. See the references on [this page](http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/histogram/index.html) that should let you avoid the problem of p-hacking.

Comment: @Kodiologist I believe context is irrelevant to my question as it could apply to any statistical study (ie what is the best goodness-of-fit test given the data above, and/or is it legitimative to modify the bin width). Anyway, since you asked, I'll just say I'm doing a research internship that could possibly lead to a publication. So this is why I don't want to do anything too shady with my data like p-hacking.

Comment: @DavidLane Thank you. I found some rules of thumb like the [Freedman-Diaconis rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman–Diaconis_rule) which seems to be an objective solution. However, I find that my optimal bin size should be around 9 times its initial width, so the number of bins is reduced to about 10-11 (by comparison with 100 initially). It seems pretty extreme to get 6 parameters (4 of which are very important for my study, so it has to be extremely precise) out of a 10-bin histogram fit. Could I justify a smaller bin size objectively, say in a scientific article? Thanks.

Comment: The  critical thing is that the bin size should not be chosen based on how it affects the significance of your subsequent statistical test.

Comment: "I believe context is irrelevant to my question" — Certainly not. [Statistics isn't a machine that takes numbers in one end and produces APA-style results sections out the other.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3181) The right tool for the job depends on things like where the data came from, what the variables measure, and what you're trying to accomplish. In particular, I doubt that fitting a function to a histogram will do you any good, but unless you provide [these details](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl), nobody can give you specific advice.

Comment: @Kodiologist [There you go.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900210013732) I want to reproduce the calibration method described in this article. Feel free to read, but I doubt people (including you) are wiling to get into all these details only to answer a quick question on a forum.

Comment: @Kodiologist Furthermore, it seems to me that most questions in the feed do not provide the details you ask, yet it doesn't stop people from answering or ask for _specific_ details. Anyway, I also thought that my question was long enough, and that any details regarding the why's and how's of my analysis could simply be assumed to be right. Remember that I've mentioned an internship: I have a director giving me hints as to what method to use, hints based on previous peer-reviewed publications; I am not taking this out of nowhere ;)

Comment: From the paper, it looks like no significance tests are performed, and while a histogram is presented for illustrative purposes, no binning is involved in estimating the model parameters. Least squares is mentioned repeatedly, and one doesn't generally bin data before performing a least-squares fit. So I'm not sure why you've got all these bins and $p$-values.

Comment: The paper describes the function to fit on the low energy spectrum(histogram) to get the parameters we need for the calibration. I need these parameters to describe the emprical spectrum as well as possible to later on predict the energy of a hit with a given TOT with high precision. [The framework](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/MAFalda) I'm using makes, as I've mentioned, 20-1000 tries to fit the data with different random [initial conditions](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html#a7e7d34c91d5ebab4fc9bba3ca47dabdd) and keeps the best p-value.

Comment: [Continued] By default the bin size is 1 TOT, but if you compare my data with the one in the article, I have almost twice as much bins (different detector/source, etc.). Because of this, random fluctuations are quite important and the algorithm (which should run automatically for the 256*256 pixels) can never get a satisfying p-value. Thus, it always tries 1000 fits even though the fit cannot get really better than what is illustrated above. I need to tell the algorithm that a fit like the one shown above is OK, without setting the critical p-value at 10$^{-7}$. Rebinning might be a solution?

Comment: Also, should a pixel fail to return a fit with a satisfying p-value (e.g. 10$^{-200}$ for the best fit out of 1000, which I've seen), it could mean that the pixel is malfunctioning (which is expected when developping technologies such as our detector; a few % of the pixels are defective). We could then ignore it in further analysis, for the information it gives will never be valid. Now of course, if the fit of every pixel has a very low p-value, we cannot easily identify the malfunctioning ones. So the goodness-of-fit test is useful beyond the fit itself.

Comment: I would agree that fitting the data repeatedly and only keeping the minimum $p$-value is $p$-hacking in the sense that the final $p$ will underestimate the probability of the test statistic under the null hypothesis. Backing up, though, it's better to fit the raw data points rather than bin them and fit to the bins; binning throws away a lot of the information in the data.

Comment: Isn't it how optimization/curve fitting works? You iterate on a set of parameters until you get a satisfying correspondence between the theoritical model and the empirical data (ie the _maximum_ - not minimum - $p$-value)? Also, ROOT fits distributions like mine on [TH1](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html#a7e7d34c91d5ebab4fc9bba3ca47dabdd) objets (1D histogram), so it has to be binned. [It seems to be the way CERN fits its data.](http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/observation-new-particle-mass-125-gev) In fact, I'm not sure how to fit a PDF (function in the paper) with "raw data points".

Comment: "Isn't it how optimization/curve fitting works?" — No, in those cases, the thing that is optimized is a measure of fit. A $p$-value is a diagnostic value used to do significance tests, not a measure of fit. "In fact, I'm not sure how to fit a PDF (function in the paper) with 'raw data points'." — Maximum likelihood estimation is an example of a way that a parametrized PDF can be fit using the original scores without binning.